# making a variable dynamic in if statement

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, dynamic

I am trying to do the bellow:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set choice=
set /p choice="Select File Number, or no to exit: "

if "%choice%"=="no" (
goto cleanup
) else (
set "!choice!=%choice%"
start %file!choice!%
pause
)
```

what i want is to open a file where the variable is %filex% and be able to choose what file to open

Comment: `set "!choice!=%choice%"` choice already conyains the number. There is no need for delayed expansion.

Comment: alright so i guess where I'm setting the %filex% inst working

Comment: There is no need for this line of code: `set "!choice!=%choice%"` as the variable is already set but the code is also wrong.  With your start command you will want to do this. `start "" "!file%choice%!"`